# Glob matching file or directory

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, glob, node-glob

I'm using node-glob, https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob.
My structure is:

```
img/
 -/nested
     image1.png
     image2.jpg
 -/emtpy
 image1.png
 image2.jpg
```

I'm trying to get all the images + empty directories

Using

> '**/*+(.jpg|.png)'

Results in:

```
[
    "img/nested/image1.png",
    "img/nested/image2.jpg",
    "img/image1.png",
    "img/image2.png"
]
```

Using

> '**/*/'

Works as expected:

```
[
    "img/",
    "img/empty/",
    "img/nested/"
]
```

Trying to combine both results doesn't work at all

> '**/*+(.jpg|.png|/)'

Empty array

```
 []
```

I would like to have 2 results combined in something like:

```
[
    "img/",
    "img/empty/",
    "img/nested/"
    "img/nested/image1.png",
    "img/nested/image2.jpg",
    "img/image1.png",
    "img/image2.png",
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final solution of our common experimenting session in comments: `'**/*{/,+(.jpg|.png)}'`

Comment: Nope, it returns empty array

Comment: I just edited, sorry, did you test latest version? `'**/?(*.jpg|*.png)'`

Comment: This one '**/?(*.jpg|*.png)' returns all images in all folders, folders are not included

Comment: Hum, odd. Then only idea I have left is `'**/?(*.jpg|*.png|*/)'` but it really seems like it doesn't want to combine files and folders :(

Comment: This one `'**/?(*.jpg|*.png|*/)'` returns empty array, I think glob is extremely powerful, I'm quite sure there is a solution and I will proceed with it :)

Comment: Um, did you or didn't you use `**` in the beginning? Either way, good luck :)

Comment: I read the docs again, so one more try: `'**/*/?(*.jpg|*.png)'` sorry xD I appreciate you testing them :)

Comment: and if even that fails, maybe braces can do the trick  `'**/*{/,+(.jpg|.png)}'`

Comment: This one works as expected `'**/*{/,+(.jpg|.png)}'`, thanks!